# What element of the array would be the median if the the size of the array was even and not odd?

Tags: quicksort

I read that it's possible to make quicksort run at O(nlogn)

the algorithm says on each step choose the median as a pivot

but, suppose we have this array:

```
10 8 39 2 9 20
```

which value will be the median?

In math if I remember correct the median is (39+2)/2 = 41/2 = 20.5

I don't have a 20.5 in my array though

thanks in advance

Comment: Note: your memory of the media is not correct- it's not the mean of the largest and smallest items, it's the item that falls in the middle of the sorted list.  So for your example, the median is 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can choose either of them; if you consider the input as a limit, it does not matter as it scales up.

Comment: If array has odd number of elements say 5, you pick the middle one after sorting the array, i.e. 2, 8, *9*, 10, 20. If the array is even, in your example: 2, 8, |9, 10|, 20, 39, you get (9+10)/2=9.5.

Answer (score 1):

We're talking about the exact wording of the description of an algorithm here, and I don't have the text you're referring to. But I think in context by "median" they probably meant, not the mathematical median of the values in the list, but rather the middle point in the list, i.e. the median INDEX, which in this cade would be 3 or 4. As coffNjava says, you can take either one.

Answer (score 0):

The median is actually found by sorting the array first, so in your example, the median is found by arranging the numbers as 2 8 9 10 20 39 and the median would be the mean of the two middle elements, (9+10)/2 = 9.5, which doesn't help you at all. Using the median is sort of an ideal situation, but would work if the array were at least already partially sorted, I think.

With an even numbered array, you can't find an exact pivot point, so I believe you can use either of the middle numbers. It'll throw off the efficiency a bit, but not substantially unless you always ended up sorting even arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the median of an unsorted set of numbers can be done in O(N) time, but it's not really necessary to find the true median for the purposes of quicksort's pivot. You just need to find a pivot that's reasonable.

As the [Wikipedia entry for quicksort says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot):

> In very early versions of quicksort, the leftmost element of the partition would often be chosen as the pivot element. Unfortunately, this causes worst-case behavior on already sorted arrays, which is a rather common use-case. The problem was easily solved by choosing either a random index for the pivot, choosing the middle index of the partition or (especially for longer partitions) choosing the median of the first, middle and last element of the partition for the pivot (as recommended by R. Sedgewick).

Finding the median of three values is much easier than finding it for the whole collection of values, and for collections that have an even number of elements, it doesn't really matter which of the two 'middle' elements you choose as the potential pivot.